# Multiple JSON Object Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine

How would i go about making multiple JSON arrays from 1 JSON array?

Basically i have an array filled with JSON objects, but i
would like to create multiple arrays with each array
being filled with specific JSON objects from the initial array
depending on a certain property like ID that every JSON object posesses.

I work in Unity3D with C#.

Anyone any ideas?

**[EDIT]**

this is 1 object:

{"ID":175355,"Datetime":1523612270,"Module":"Krol 42","Latitude":52.08618,"Longitude":5.11126166666667,"Speed":0}

There are 50 different object with individual IDs in the array
but every ID has a 100 instances of it with different lat/lon coordinates

so what i would like is to have an array filled with 50 arrays, so each
unique ID has its own array with all the 100 different instances of it in it.

if this makes any sense, i dont know if im explaining it clearly enough, sorry about that.

Comment: In what form are your JSON objects? `dynamic`?

Comment: what did you try so far? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Personally I'd probably deserialise the source json array, use linq queries and .ToArray() to generate the new arrays based on whatever criteria I required, and then serialise back to json. Without knowing more about the objects involved and the expected outcome etc, it's somewhat hard to say though.

Comment: please edit your question and add sample json and expected result

Comment: @Efrain they do change, yes.

Comment: @R.Bechtel i have looked into array of arrays and i know its possible but i have no clue how id go about it in my case, cant really wrap my head around it, im not used to working with JSON

Comment: @derloopkat i hope this clearifies it a bit more

Comment: @Diado it seems like you definitely know what you are talking about, unfortunately me myself are totally unexpirienced with JSON, i edited the question, i hope it made it a bit more clear of what i exactly want to achieve.

Comment: @Bosanac95 take a look at CodeCaster's answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Generate a class](http://json2csharp.com/) to hold the JSON data:

```
public class ModuleInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Datetime { get; set; }
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the JSON array:

```
var moduleInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModuleInfo>>(jsonString);
```

Then group by Id using Linq:

```
var groupedModuleInfo = moduleInfo.GroupBy(m => m.ID).ToArray();
```

Then you can serialize that array again:

```
var groupedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupedModuleInfo);
```

This will yield an array of arrays, where each inner array contains all records for one ID:

```
[[{
        "ID": 60034,
        "Datetime": 1519029071,
        "Module": "Krol 42",
        "Latitude": 51.8423083333333,
        "Longitude": 4.57711,
        "Speed": 0.59264
    }
], [{
        "ID": 58961,
        "Datetime": 1519025476,
        "Module": "Krol 42",
        "Latitude": 51.8422666666667,
        "Longitude": 4.576865,
        "Speed": 0.59264
    }
]]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @CodeCaster :D